# How to clear the link warning 4099

Tags: visual-c++, linker

In my vc2005 solution , when build it ,some warning will displayed such as "warning LNK4099: PDB 'libbmt.pdb' was not found...", But I don't know to to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be disabled, as it is on Microsoft's list of unignorable warnings.

If you have the source for the libraries you are using, you can rebuild them in Debug mode and copy the generated *.pdb files to the same directory as the libs you are linking.

If you do not have the source, there is a workaround, but it involves hex-editing the linker: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/176188/can-not-disable-warning-lnk4099

> Essentially, hex edit your link.exe (after backing it up!) to zap the
>   occurrence of 4099 in the list of non-ignorable warnings. I did it and
>   the hundred or so 4099 warnings disappeared! [L]ook
>   for the hex bytes 03 10 00 00 (which is 4099 as a 32-bit little-endian
>   hex value). Change it to (say) FF FF 00 00, save the file and you're
>   done.

Comment: IME, that only masks the problem, since the project cannot be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VS2005 but in newer versions you can ignore specific link warnings by adding `/ignore:4099`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This does not solve an issue; it's simply hiding the issue. While this does "fix it" this should be a last resort. And commented after a successful fix is found